# Sorting a string array based on number of occurances in R

Tags: r

Input:

```
Array = {"one", "two", "three", "three", "three","two"}
```

Output should be :

```
NewArray = {"three", "two", "one"}
```

Whats is the **simplest and best** way of doing it in R. I know that it can be done by taking hash package into consideration or even env's.
any less than 5 lines of code?

Comment: You need to sort strings `"three", "two", "one"` by their _parsed_ value (`3, 2, 1`) instead of a string comparison (that would give `"one", "three" "two"`)? In that case `NewArray <- Array[!duplicated(Array)])` then `sort(NewArray)` isn't enough. How did you manage parsing so far?

Comment: @Adriano No. By number of occurances. for example. three occurred 3 times and two occurred twice. So "three" comes first, then "two", then "one"(since one occurs only once).

Comment: Did you try with `sort(table(Array), decreasing = TRUE)`?

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to extract bins (after sort you still have bins and frequencies tied together). Take a look to @Troy's solution too, not so clar at first sight but it may be more efficient for large sets.

Comment: -1 for failing to use R syntax in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with `count()` from `plyr':

```
require(plyr)
counts<-count(c("one", "two", "three", "three", "three","two"))
NewArray<-array(counts[order(-counts$freq),1])
```